# Printing values from map based on index

Tags: java

If I have following map:

```
 NavigableMap<Integer,String> nmap = 
        new TreeMap<Integer,String>(); 

    nmap.put(3, "Three"); 
    nmap.put(1, "One"); 
    nmap.put(4, "Four"); 
    nmap.put(5, "Five"); 
    nmap.put(7, "Seven"); 
    nmap.put(10, "Ten"); 


System.out.println(nmap); 
// {1=One, 3=Three, 4=Four, 5=Five, 7=Seven, 10=Ten}
```

Is there a mechanism, that can allow me to print this, printing by index value, if index is smaller more than 1 from the following index print -(dash):

> One,-,Three,Four,Five,-,Six,Seven,-,-,Ten

How would I write function for this?

I don't have to print whole map to string I meant for each key/value pair

Comment: Do you actually want to turn it into a string? Or do you want an array like: `{"One",null,"Three","Four","Five",null,null,"Seven"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generalized solution, that also does the concatenation. My generics knownledge is a bit dodgy, so don't be surprised by the odd mistake:

```
static <V> List<V> NMapToList(NavigableMap<Integer,V> nmap, V emptyEntryValue)
{
    Integer next = null;
    List<V> list = new ArrayList<V>();

    for(NavigableMap.Entry<Integer, V> e : nmap.entrySet())
    {
        Integer current = e.getKey();

        if(next != null)
            for(int i = next; i < current; i++)
                list.add(emptyEntryValue);
        list.add(e.getValue());

        next = current + 1;
    }

    return list;
}

static String listToString(List<?> l, String separator)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
    String sep = "";
    for (Object object : l)
    {
        sb.append(sep).append(object.toString());
        sep = separator;
    }
    return sb.append(")").toString();
}

String s = listToString(NMapToList(nmap,'-'),',');
```

Comment: you're at the right track, but I get this output [One, , Four, Five, ]

Comment: I don't see the difference. I've made another change. I forgot to provide arguments

Comment: Right, fixed now. I wasn't adding the element to the list after filling blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should work:

```
public String myToString(final NavigableMap<Integer, String> nmap) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Integer lastKey = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : nmap.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = entry.getKey();
        if (lastKey != null) {
            for (int i=(lastKey+1); i<key; i++) {
                sb.append(",-");
            }
        }
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.append(",");
        }
        sb.append(entry.getValue());
        lastKey = key;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I fixed this code to compile, here it is http://pastebin.ca/1906823 but it produces this output ,One,Three,Four,Five,Seven I don't have a clue how to fix it

Comment: @Gandalf: that's because your fix was wrong. `.equals(null)` doesn't ever produce anything useful. And I never wanted to call `.lastKey()` on the `Map`. I've fixed the code now. It compiles and produces the correct output for me.

Comment: this works if only one map key is missing, i.e `One,-,Three,Four,Five,-,Six` but not if the case is more than one is missing i.e `One,-,Three,Four,Five,-,Six,-,-,Nine` I updated my question

Comment: @Gandalf: I see. Your original spec didn't require that, but it's easy enough to change.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new subclass of TreeMap and override the toString method.

Comment: I don't have to print whole map to string I meant for earh key/value pair

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NavigableSet<K> navigableKeySet()` method of the NavigableMap, which returns a NavigableSet view of the keys contained in this map. The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order. Then iterate on the Set and get the values from the NavigableMap.

Edit:
To use this `System.out.println(nmap);` you should subclass from NavigableMap and override the `toString()` method, using the steps I wrote earlier.

Comment: No, it;s better to iterate the keys through `entrySet()`: `for(NavigableMap.Entry<Integer, V> e : nmap.entrySet())`